# How do I get this chest in Vah Naboris Dungeon?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

There is a chest in Vah Naboris Dungeon that is elusive and hard to get to.

> If you head to the tail section on the bottom, I don't see any way to get the content, and most walk-throughs skip over chests, from what I've seen. I don't see any water or magnetic objects that could act like a plank to catch it. For reference, [this is the chest I am talking about at 1:07 (link to Youtube walk-through video)](https://youtu.be/NKKi2Jc7yTI?t=67).
>
>  The only way I can think of is to raise the tail section up and shoot it from there, but it is harder to aim.

This chest is tricky to get since if I shoot the wire holding it up, it will fall down, and you can't retrieve the content whatsoever.

Using stasis and trying to catch it with magnetic doesn't help because stasis itself blocks magnetic and will just fall too fast for you to "catch" it with magnetic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like you, I initially had the thought of "Stasis -> Cut Rope -> Grab with Magnesis", but I found that difficult to pull off, since Magnesis has a projectile (stasis doesn't).

What I found to be easier was to use Magnesis on the chest with the rope still attached, such that it rocked back and forth. During one of the forward swings (when the chest was above the platform), I hit it with Stasis, and only then cut the rope.

This resulted in the chest landing nicely in front of me once stasis wore off. As you yourself found, this chest contains an ancient core.

Comment: I am still having trouble doing this on Wii U. If I do it so that it end up being above the platform it still come up short and fall below.

Comment: @Vyndicu You need to stasis it while it still has forward momentum so that that momentum continues after the rope is cut. If you wait too long, it'll start to swing back and won't cross the gap.

Comment: I ended up needing to use magnesis on it again after it hit the platform as it began to tumble down and luckily I grabbed it through the platform itself, just another safeguard those of you struggling with this should consider doing.

Answer (score 8):

Shoot the top part of the rope with a fire arrow (**do not** hit the rope), just the top bit which will then ignite the rope, then the rope will begin to light slowly, Magnesis the chest and when it burns, it's yours.

Comment: Easiest way to get the chest IMO. No need for skill to quickly grab the chest with stasis or magnesis.

Answer (score 3):

I did this by shooting the rope with an arrow, and then catching it immediately with Magnesis. I had plenty of time to catch it, but YMMV.

If you're having trouble, you can stasis it, and wait for stasis to wear off, then immediately do Magnesis.

FWIW, the chest contains a single Ancient Core. They can be gotten elsewhere if you need them.

Comment: I did this too, though I believe I stasised the chest first. Got it first time.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate method I used after failing the trickshot everyone else mentioned a few times:

Lower the tail, go to the rear-most point of the tail, raise the tail. While the tail is rising, jump off and glide, and aim to land on the platform the chest is hanging from, then use magnesis to catch it while it is still swinging, and pull it up and drag it ALL THE WAY back onto the platform. If the chain is dangling off the edge, it will be enoughto drag the chest off with it. If the chest is all the way back, it will stay put and you can walk up and open it.

Answer (score 1):

So much easier: With the tail up, hit the chest with cryonis+. Then swing the tail down. The chain breaks on the way down and the chest ends up on a platform, just beneath the glowing orange orb at the tip of the tail. Climb up to the tail platform and drop down to open the chest. Simples!

Comment: Cryonis+ doesn't exist. Do you mean Stasis+?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to go to the back of the tail, raise it, then jump over to where the chest will be, then jump over another little wall, glide down to platform, bring chest up to you and open it.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed the chest from behind the bomb wall with magnesis, brought it over,  and used it to hit the rope chest while it was frozen with stasis.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the timing right, so I ended up using stasis on a forward swing then angled a Lizal boomerang so that it hit the chest towards me on the way back. I recommend having magnesis out in case it lands by a ledge, also step to the side. When it fell towards me it hit be in the head then landed in front of me.